# cant connect mysql databse using spring boot error HTTP Status 404 the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot

Below mentioned code is not fetching data with mysql database using spring boot with maven dependency.After hitting url it was not displaying any json data. Previously I was working with gradle and was able to connect with database and gives me json value. I have copied code from that to maven project, No error in code. Can anyone help me out where I am doing mistake? Please also let me know if any easy way to do the same to make code better as I am naive in this.

**1)** Running on server

Hitting Url (http://localhost:8080/CheckListMavenWebThree) throws **error** instead of giving json value.

Let you know this is maven Dynamic web project

**Error - Displays this on browser**
**HTTP Status 404 the requested resource is not available / Spring boot**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist

type Status report

message /CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
```

When I am hitting url in Postman for json data (Displays as mentioned below rather than json value from database)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.81 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /CheckListMavenWebThree/</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>/CheckListMavenWebThree/</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.81</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am confused with what url should I hit either with project name and path value (mentioned in controller class) like **8080/CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist**   or **8080/CheckListMavenWebThree** like this?

**File Structure Looks Like - >**
Structure:[File Structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNzQA.jpg)

@Controller

```
package com.example.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import com.example.Entity.Checklist;
import com.example.Service.CheckListService;
@Controller
public class CheckListController {
    @Autowired
    private CheckListService checkListService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/checklist" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object index() {
        return checkListService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(@RequestBody Checklist checklist) {
        String userSiteName = "";
        try {
            checkListService.save(checklist);

            userSiteName = String.valueOf(checklist.getSite_Name());
            System.out.println(userSiteName);
            System.out.println(checklist.getWSC_Serial_Number());
            System.out.println(checklist.getSetup_Tech());
            System.out.println(checklist.getDate());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_01());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_02());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_03());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_04());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_05());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_06());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_07());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_08());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_09());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_10());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_11());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_12());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_13());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCheckList_14());
            System.out.println(checklist.getNotes());
            System.out.println(checklist.getCompleted_By());
            System.out.println(checklist.toString());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
        return userSiteName;
    }
}
```

@Application Main

```
package com.example.Main;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.Repository")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = com.example.Entity.Checklist.class)
public class SmartRainCheckListApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmartRainCheckListApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

@Entity

```
package com.example.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "checklist")
public class Checklist {

    public Checklist() {

    }

    @Column(name = "Site_Name")
    private String Site_Name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "WSC_Serial_Number")
    private Long WSC_Serial_Number;

    public Checklist(Long wsc_serial_number) {
        this.WSC_Serial_Number = wsc_serial_number;
    }

    @Column(name = "Setup_Tech")
    private String Setup_Tech;

    @Column(name = "Date")
    private String Date;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_01")
    private String CheckList_01;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_02")
    private String CheckList_02;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_03")
    private String CheckList_03;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_04")
    private String CheckList_04;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_05")
    private String CheckList_05;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_06")
    private String CheckList_06;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_07")
    private String CheckList_07;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_08")
    private String CheckList_08;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_09")
    private String CheckList_09;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_10")
    private String CheckList_10;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_11")
    private String CheckList_11;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_12")
    private String CheckList_12;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_13")
    private String CheckList_13;

    @Column(name = "CheckList_14")
    private String CheckList_14;

    @Column(name = "Notes")
    private String Notes;

    @Column(name = "Completed_By")
    private String Completed_By;

    // public Checklist(String Site_Name, Long WSC_Serial_Number, String
    // Setup_Tech, String Date, String CheckList_01,
    // String CheckList_02) {
    // this.Site_Name = Site_Name;
    // this.WSC_Serial_Number = WSC_Serial_Number;
    // this.Setup_Tech = Setup_Tech;
    // this.Date = Date;
    // this.CheckList_01 = CheckList_01;
    // this.CheckList_02 = CheckList_02;
    // }

    public Checklist(String site_Name, Long wSC_Serial_Number, String setup_Tech, String date, String checkList_01,
            String checkList_02, String checkList_03, String checkList_04, String checkList_05, String checkList_06,
            String checkList_07, String checkList_08, String checkList_09, String checkList_10, String checkList_11,
            String checkList_12, String checkList_13, String checkList_14, String notes, String completed_By) {
        super();
        Site_Name = site_Name;
        WSC_Serial_Number = wSC_Serial_Number;
        Setup_Tech = setup_Tech;
        Date = date;
        CheckList_01 = checkList_01;
        CheckList_02 = checkList_02;
        CheckList_03 = checkList_03;
        CheckList_04 = checkList_04;
        CheckList_05 = checkList_05;
        CheckList_06 = checkList_06;
        CheckList_07 = checkList_07;
        CheckList_08 = checkList_08;
        CheckList_09 = checkList_09;
        CheckList_10 = checkList_10;
        CheckList_11 = checkList_11;
        CheckList_12 = checkList_12;
        CheckList_13 = checkList_13;
        CheckList_14 = checkList_14;
        Notes = notes;
        Completed_By = completed_By;
    }

    public String getSite_Name() {
        return Site_Name;
    }

    public void setSite_Name(String site_Name) {
        Site_Name = site_Name;
    }

    public Long getWSC_Serial_Number() {
        return 0 + + WSC_Serial_Number;
    } 

    public void setWSC_Serial_Number(Long WSC_Serial_Number) {
        this.WSC_Serial_Number = WSC_Serial_Number;
    }

    public String getSetup_Tech() {
        return Setup_Tech;
    }

    public void setSetup_Tech(String setup_Tech) {
        this.Setup_Tech = setup_Tech;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.Date = date;
    }

    public String getCheckList_01() {
        return CheckList_01;
    }

    public void setCheckList_01(String CheckList_01) {
        this.CheckList_01 = CheckList_01;
    }

    public String getCheckList_02() {
        return CheckList_02;
    }

    public void setCheckList_02(String CheckList_02) {
        this.CheckList_02 = CheckList_02;
    }

    public String getCheckList_03() {
        return CheckList_03;
    }

    public void setCheckList_03(String checkList_03) {
        CheckList_03 = checkList_03;
    }

    public String getCheckList_04() {
        return CheckList_04;
    }

    public void setCheckList_04(String checkList_04) {
        CheckList_04 = checkList_04;
    }

    public String getCheckList_05() {
        return CheckList_05;
    }

    public void setCheckList_05(String checkList_05) {
        CheckList_05 = checkList_05;
    }

    public String getCheckList_06() {
        return CheckList_06;
    }

    public void setCheckList_06(String checkList_06) {
        CheckList_06 = checkList_06;
    }

    public String getCheckList_07() {
        return CheckList_07;
    }

    public void setCheckList_07(String checkList_07) {
        CheckList_07 = checkList_07;
    }

    public String getCheckList_08() {
        return CheckList_08;
    }

    public void setCheckList_08(String checkList_08) {
        CheckList_08 = checkList_08;
    }

    public String getCheckList_09() {
        return CheckList_09;
    }

    public void setCheckList_09(String checkList_09) {
        CheckList_09 = checkList_09;
    }

    public String getCheckList_10() {
        return CheckList_10;
    }

    public void setCheckList_10(String checkList_10) {
        CheckList_10 = checkList_10;
    }

    public String getCheckList_11() {
        return CheckList_11;
    }

    public void setCheckList_11(String checkList_11) {
        CheckList_11 = checkList_11;
    }

    public String getCheckList_12() {
        return CheckList_12;
    }

    public void setCheckList_12(String checkList_12) {
        CheckList_12 = checkList_12;
    }

    public String getCheckList_13() {
        return CheckList_13;
    }

    public void setCheckList_13(String checkList_13) {
        CheckList_13 = checkList_13;
    }

    public String getCheckList_14() {
        return CheckList_14;
    }

    public void setCheckList_14(String checkList_14) {
        CheckList_14 = checkList_14;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return Notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        Notes = notes;
    }

    public String getCompleted_By() {
        return Completed_By;
    }

    public void setCompleted_By(String completed_By) {
        Completed_By = completed_By;
    }

}
```

@Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/smartraindb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#naming convention according to me
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

@ Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CheckListMavenWebThree</groupId>
    <artifactId>CheckListMavenWebThree</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**2)** When I tried differently , running as spring boot app it **throws error**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-08-18 12:51:33.066  INFO 56824 --- [           main] c.e.Main.SmartRainCheckListApplication   : Starting SmartRainCheckListApplication on H-H-Temp with PID 56824 (C:\Users\keval.shah\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE-new\CheckListMavenWebThree\target\classes started by Keval.Shah in C:\Users\keval.shah\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE-new\CheckListMavenWebThree)
2017-08-18 12:51:33.068  INFO 56824 --- [           main] c.e.Main.SmartRainCheckListApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-18 12:51:33.108  INFO 56824 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@448ff1a8: startup date [Fri Aug 18 12:51:33 MDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-18 12:51:33.827  INFO 56824 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2017-08-18 12:51:34.365  WARN 56824 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
2017-08-18 12:51:34.373  INFO 56824 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-18 12:51:34.380 ERROR 56824 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Main.SmartRainCheckListApplication.main(SmartRainCheckListApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner$Tomcat8TldSkipSetter.setSkipPattern(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:106) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.setPatternToTomcat8SkipFilter(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:61) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.<init>(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:56) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.apply(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:87) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:209) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:178) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what is the error ? share your pom.xml

Comment: Unable to fetching data(not displaying json file) as mentioned above when I was hitting url. I have also added pom.xml. It was able to return json file after hitting urlwhen i was working with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the context path `CheckListMavenWebThree` is not defined in your properties, so `http://localhost:8080/CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist` it's going to throw 404. You add to your properties file:

`server.contextPath=/CheckListMavenWebThree`

or just hit your app like this,

`http://localhost:8080/checklist`

Hope this helps